# How to resize UIView which has auto-layout constraints using setFrame:

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimageview, cgrect, autolayout

My `UIViewController` contains a custom `UIView` with several sub views embedded in it.

In a particular case when a user taps on a `UIImageView` thumbnail (which is in the custom `UIView`), the UIViewController gets a delegate call notifying of that.

The view controller "wants" to expand this thumbnail to a larger size. In theory I think I should do this by removing the `UIImageView` from its super view, adding it back again to the view controller's view (or key window) at the front most position, and then resizing and placing it accordingly.

For instance:

```
// delegate method for image view being tapped
-(void)customView:(CustomView *)customView imageViewWasTapped:(UIImageView *)imageView
{
  [imageView removeFromSuperview];
  [self.view addSubview:imageView];
  [self.view bringSubviewToFront:imageView];
  UIView animateWithDuration:2 animations:^{
    imageView.frame = someNewFrame;
  }];
}
```

But this isn't working properly and the `UIImageView` looks screwed up completely. I think that the `NSAutoLayoutConstraints` that the custom view has attached to the UIImageView are interfering with the placement in the `UIViewController`'s view system.

I'm not sure if I need to remove the constraints before assigning the `UIImageView` to a new super view, because at a later time I plan on returning the UIImageView to its original parent container view (original super view) - and I want its frame to be returned to the original one it had (think Facebook app when tapping on an image - it expands to full size. when finished returns to its original location).

If this is the case - how should I go about "temporarily" changing a `UIView`'s `NSAutoLayoutConstraints` with out any notion of its parent's placement of this `UIView` (Eventually I would need to revert to the original constraints)

Comment: Do you really need to remove the image view from the custom view to expand it? Is it still within (or partly within) the custom view? It certainly would be easier to leave it where it is (in the hierarchy) and change its size, if that works (but if it still needs to be tappable, any part outside the bounds of its superview won't respond to the tap).

Comment: "I think that the NSAutoLayoutConstraints that the custom view has attached to the UIImageView are interfering with the placement in the UIViewController's view system." -- this shouldn't be true. When you remove a view from its superview, any constraints that superview had for it are removed also. If the image view itself has constraints (for width or height), those will still remain.

Comment: the view is being relarged to a greater size than its super view so it has to be removed.